# How can I automatically pass the password to 'su'?

Tags: linux, root, su, passwd, exploit

I am working on an exploit for a security course. The object is to obtain a root shell in a linux virtual machine. So far, I can write to /etc/passwd and change root's password to an arbitrary string.

Now, I want to use su to get the root shell. Since my exploit has to be automated, it can't prompt for a password, and the vm doesn't have expect installed. Does anybody have any idea how I can pass the password to the su command? Or is there a better way?

Comment: If you are able to write to /etc/passwd, then surely you have already elevated to root?  In that case, couldn't you setuid on /bin/bash and run it?

Comment: I don't have root on the vm. We are to exploit a given backup program that has setuid set. By passing it malicious arguments I can get it to change the owner of /etc/passwd.

Comment: Can you pass the setuid process malicious arguments to do a setuid on /bin/bash?

Comment: @noobler Do you have the source for the backup program? If not, you need to find a buffer overflow by trial and error. `su` opens /dev/tty to read the password. You need to find a way to persuade `su` to use your very own /dev/tty.

Comment: If you can have the setuid program call `chmod` to change permissions of /etc/password as root, why can't you just have the setuid program call `/bin/bash` to spawn a root shell?

Answer (score 0):

The best ways to automate this type of input, is using `expect` or better `pexpect`.
most servers come with python, at least with a modern distribution.

First off you said your VM does not have `expect` installed?   I'm not sure why that matters.  Is there any reason why you cannot install/execute something, under your local account?

Next consideration, why must you even use `passwd`??? You can also change a password by replacing the hash specified in `/etc/shadow`.  You obviously would need to correctly pregenerate a hash first, but as long as you use a supported one it should work as expected. Now how you would script such an action, that's an exercise for you to work out.

I also want to mention, `passwd` does not read it's input from STDIN.  If i'm not mistaken, it reads from a tty. So no fancy combo of just `echo` and `sleep` would work. However it's possible using a HEREDOC, but assumes system is sufficiently responsive.  You may be able to break it up and `sleep` between entires.  I just tested this, it worked on my Ubuntu workstation.

```
#!/bin/bash
passwd root <<'EOF'
newpassword
newpassword
EOF
```

Answer (score -2):

Your exploit could also write to the groups file and make the current user part of the 'wheel' group (or whatever group can run `sudo` commands w/o a password).  Then you'll be able to `sudo su root` (or any other user) w/o a password.

Running `visudo` should give you some direction on the setup of the 'wheel' group on your machine.

To clarify: once a user becomes part of the wheel group, they can run sudo commands without needing a password.

Comment: Sudo is not installed on the vm..